# How to use mediastore.audio for album and artist info and add it in custom list view?

Tags: android, mp3, mediastore, custom-lists

First of all i am a newbie,here is the code for adding the song's name in the customlost ,all i need is just some function using mediastore(i tried metadataretriever but the app stopped responding ) so that i can add them too....

public class FragmentSongs extends  Fragment {

```
    private MediaPlayer mp =new MediaPlayer();



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        ListView SngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SongList);
        File f=new File("/sdcard");
        ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo = getSongsFromDirectory(f);
        if (Songinfo.size()>0){
           SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo));
           return view;
        }
        else return null;

    }


        public ArrayList<SongDetails> getSongsFromDirectory(File f)
        {// MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

            ArrayList<SongDetails> songs = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
            if (!f.exists() || !f.isDirectory()) 

            {    
                return songs;
            }
            File[] files = f.listFiles(new Mp3Filter());
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
            { 

            if (files[i].isFile()){
          //    metaRetriever.setDataSource(files[i].getName());
            //metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
            SongDetails detail=new SongDetails(); 
            detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
            String fileName = files[i].getName(); 
            detail.setSong(files[i].getName()); 

            detail.setArtist(files[i].getName()); 
            detail.setAlbum(files[i].getName()); 
            songs.add(detail); 
            }else if (files[i].isDirectory()){ 
            songs.addAll(getSongsFromDirectory(files[i])); 
            } 

            }

            return songs;



    } }
class Mp3Filter implements FileFilter{
    public boolean accept(File file){
       return (file.isDirectory()||file.getName().endsWith(".MP3")|| file.getName().endsWith(".mp3"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the precise question is but if you are looking to add song titles to a custom list, why not use something like this

```
    final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID; 
    final String track_no =MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    final String track_name =MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
    final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
    final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
    final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER;
    final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
public Cursor getTrackTrackcursor(Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    // gets all tracks
    ContentResolver cr =  context.getContentResolver();
    final String[]columns={track_id, track_no, artist, track_name,album, duration, path, year, composer};
    cursor = cr.query(uri,columns,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: well thanx for your time,but how can i add it it my list?

Comment: Once you have your cursor you loop through it by going cursor.movefirst(), cursor.movenext() etc. Each loop you add the data cursor.getString(<column>) to your adapter listitems.Let me know if you are stuck.

Comment: Can you explain the code little further. What If I wan to implement this cursor inside the fragment